# Apache POI: German cell format in concatenated string cell

Tags: java, localization, apache-poi, locale

I've got an Excel-(xlsx-)file with two cells:

- A1 is numeric with value "5.3"
- B1 is formula ="Number: "&A1

When I open this Excel-file in German LibreOffice or Excel then both show me cell content with comma-separator:

- A1: 5,3
- B1: Number: 5,3

When I read the contents with Apache POI (version 3.17; `new DataFormatter(Locale.GERMAN).formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator)`), the numeric cell A1 is correctly formatted as "5,3", but the concatenated cell B1 is unexpectedly formatted with a dot as a separator.

Here is my sample code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class MiniPoiTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // doesn't change anything
    // LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

    // read workbook
    File xlsxFile = new File("string-concat.xlsx");
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(xlsxFile);
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    formulaEvaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // read two cells
    Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
    Cell numericCell = row.getCell(0);
    Cell concatenatedCell = row.getCell(1);

    // print numeric cell
    String numericCellValue = new DataFormatter(Locale.GERMAN).formatCellValue(numericCell,
            formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.println("Value in " + numericCell.getAddress().formatAsString()
            + " (numeric cell): '" + numericCellValue + "'");

    // print concatenated cell
    String concatenatedCellValue = new DataFormatter(Locale.GERMAN)
            .formatCellValue(concatenatedCell, formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.println("Value in " + concatenatedCell.getAddress().formatAsString()
            + " (concatenated cell): '" + concatenatedCellValue + "'");
    System.out.println("Formula in " + concatenatedCell.getAddress().formatAsString()
            + " (concatenated cell): '" + concatenatedCell.getCellFormula() + "'");
  }

}
```

Result when executing the sample code:

```
Value in A1 (numeric cell): '5,3'
Value in B1 (concatenated cell): 'Number: 5.3'
Formula in B1 (concatenated cell): '"Number: "&A1'
```

Is there some trick to get the concatenated content of B1 also formatted with a German numeric separator ("Number: 5,3")?

Comment: What happens [if you tell Apache POI to use the German locale for everything](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleUtil.html#setUserLocale-java.util.Locale-) before you do the evaluation?

Comment: Calling `LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(Locale.GERMAN)` does not change anything. It's the same output: 'Number: 5.3'.

Comment: The problem is that `DataFormatter` is able using different locales but `FormulaEvaluator` is not. And `DataFormatter` will not changing dot to comma when it gets a string from the `FormulaEvaluator`. `FormulaEvaluator` converts numbers to strings using [NumberToTextConverter](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/NumberToTextConverter.java?view=markup). This will always using dot as decimal delimiter because this is hard coded there. So no solution here until `apache poi` will making `FormulaEvaluator` also able using different locales.

Comment: @Axel Richter: Thank you for that detailed answer.Then I'll try to replace the separator chars with Excel-formulas.